# Unnecessary filter code execution in custom filter class

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

### Issue-1

- Even if we don't pass any `tag` in the request query the function `datasetfiletagsquery` gets executed

### Issue-2

- If I set `dataset_id` as required then it is enforced in `retrieve` and other `action` api functions as well.

### Context

- I need to make `dataset_id` as the required query only when `tag` query is passed in the request

### Code

```py
class DatasetFileViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, GenericViewSet):

    class DatasetFileFilter(filters.FilterSet):

        def datasetfiletagsquery(request):
            try:
                dataset_id = request.query_params['dataset_id']
                qs = Tag.objects.filter(object_id=dataset_id, content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Dataset),
                                        category=Tag.CategoryChoices.DATASET_FILE)
            except KeyError:
                raise serializers.ValidationError({'dataset_id': 'This query is required'})
            return qs

        def datasetfiletagsfilter(queryset, name, value):
            tag_ids = [tag.pk for tag in value]
            qs = queryset.filter_by_tags(tag_ids)
            return qs

        dataset_id = filters.NumberFilter()
        tag = filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=datasetfiletagsquery, to_field_name='name', method=datasetfiletagsfilter)

        class Meta:
            model = DatasetFile
            fields = ['dataset_id', 'tag']

    queryset = DatasetFile.objects.prefetch_related('tags', 'related_child_dataset_files__child').select_related('datasetbatchfile').extend_order_by()
    serializer_class = DatasetFileSerializer
    filterset_class = DatasetFileFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.action == 'download':
            qs = DatasetFile.objects.all()
        else:
            qs = super().get_queryset()
        qs = qs.filter(dataset__organization_id=self.request.user.organization_id)
        return qs

    @action(methods=['POST'], detail=True, url_path='download', serializer_class=DatasetFileDownloadSerializer)
    def download(self, request, pk):
        """
        api for downloading dataset file
        """
        instance = self.get_object()
        instance = instance.dataset.get_datasetfiles_for_download(datasetfile_ids=[instance.pk])[0]
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

### Expected execution for issue 1

- The `datasetfiletagsquery` function should not be executed if no `tag` query is present in the request

### Expected execution for issue 2

- The `required` fields for the filter must be enforced only for the `list` api.

Answer (score 3):

The `datasetfiletagsquery` is executed to get all possible values for filtering by tag. It is executed in two situations:

1. If tag is provided, it is checked whether it is an allowed tag (this is expected by you).
2. If tag is not provided, the user can request with OPTIONS http method to get allowed options for the filter. Also this is useful for REST APIs to display possible values in the dropdown on a webpage.

So there is no possibility to make it not executed, the DRF enforces it in its code. The only possibility here for you is to remove the `queryset= datasetfiletagsquery` attribute from the filter field and to validate whether the tag is allowed or not manually while filtering.

The second issue is probably also not solveable straightforward unless you make it non-required by the DRF and validate it manually during filtering. This also will cause wrong schema of the endpoint (it won't indicate that those fields are required in list method). If this is a problem for you, you could override schema to your own manually created schema.

Also, there is a rule on stackoverflow that you need to address only one issue per question.

Comment: The second point is incorrect. `datasetfiletagsquery` is not executed on `OPTIONS` request.

Answer (score 0):

To address Issue 1, modify datasetfiletagsquery in DatasetFileViewSet to return an empty or default queryset if the 'tag' parameter is absent in the request. For Issue 2, override get_filterset_kwargs in the same viewset to dynamically set dataset_id as required only when a tag query is present, allowing you to enforce this condition selectively based on the request's context. This solution ensures efficient and context-sensitive filtering in your Django application.

You can try this code modifications:

```py
class DatasetFileViewSet(...):
    # ... your existing code code ...

    def datasetfiletagsquery(request):
        # Check if 'tag' parameter is present
        if 'tag' not in request.query_params:
            return Tag.objects.none()  # or your default queryset
        # ... rest of the function ...

    def get_filterset_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_filterset_kwargs()
        if 'tag' in self.request.query_params:
            # Adjust the 'dataset_id' filter to be required
            # This may involve custom logic to modify the filter attributes
        return kwargs

    # ... rest of the viewset ...
```

Comment: `get_filterset_kwargs` method does not exist as supermethod